# How Do You Launch The Finder Process in Terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line

Is it possible to start the Finder process from Terminal? If so, what would be the command?

Comment: The Finder is started at login and runs all the time a user is logged in so it is open all the time. What exactly are you after?

Comment: It is possible to quit the Finder in any number of ways. You can even add the Command-Q option to the user interface by typing in this Terminal command: `defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool true`

Comment: I had set Finder to relaunch but it would not turn back on after shutting off. The issue was caused by this issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176270/app-crashes-dock-icon-remains-cant-reboot-yet-no-process-in-ps-aux-to-kill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

`open /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app`

Comment: You can also open the current working directory in Finder with `open .`

Comment: This command does nothing (not even output an error) under macOS Sonoma (at least in 14.1.2)

Comment: I just tested this command when the Finder **is not running** (see my comment in the original question about how to quit Finder with ⌘-Q) and it indeed restarts Finder. If Finder _is_ running it opens a window to the root of the booted drive, or ' / '.  Executing `open .` will restart Finder and open the current user's directory. Tested on Sonoma 14.1.2