# Cannot force quit an application, which is not listed in processes but wont let computer shut down

Tags: performance, shutdown, force-quit

I was running a computationally intensive code from Rstudio, and it stopped responding. I used forcequit on the app, and tried to restart my computer. Although Rstudio wont show on ps -ax, mac refuses to shut down saying "Rstudio" is still running. When I right click on Rstudio in dock, it says "Application not responding", I think it tried to start itself and failed somehow. On DiagnosticReports I have a .hang file created after this.

My question is, how do I force quit an application when option+command+escape, or right click > Force quit does not work, pid is not listed and cannot see it running in Activity Monitor.

What might be wrong?

Comment: The power button always gets a shutdown for me.

Comment: If it's not in ps -ax I'd suspect the osx gui is having an issue. Did you try killing dock & finder?

Comment: No I tried restarting from terminal before which worked :)

Comment: Duplicate: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176270/app-crashes-dock-icon-remains-cant-reboot-yet-no-process-in-ps-aux-to-kill?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo reboot` worked, I am not sure if this causes any background issues but everything seems okay now.